# tableview reload data not working after background the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, openfire, reloaddata

I created a chat application. I have received message in this method :

```
-(void)msgRecevied:(NSMutableDictionary *)messageContent
{
    NSString *m = [messageContent objectForKey:kMsg];
    [messageContent setObject:[m substituteEmoticons] forKey:kMsg];
    [messageContent setObject:[messageContent objectForKey:kTrnDate] forKey:kTrnDate];
    [messageContent setObject:[messageContent objectForKey:kSender_User] forKey:kSender_User];
    [messageContent setObject:[messageContent objectForKey:kReceiver_User] forKey:kReceiver_User];

    [arrayChat addObject:messageContent];
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayChat);

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tblChat reloadData];
    });

    if(arrayChat.count > 1){

        NSIndexPath *topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arrayChat.count-1
                                                       inSection:0];

        [self.tblChat scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath
                            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                    animated:YES];
    }
}
```

When i received message and it reload table, than `numberOfRowsInSection` is called message is added to array, and i also printed array count in `numberOfRowsInSection` and it increase also but not called `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so can not show my message.

I also tried reloading table without main thread but not working.

What is problem there ?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"%lu",[arrayChat count]);
    return [arrayChat count];

}
```

**EDIT**

SORRY but this problem is occurred after app coming from background.

I prtinted table :

when app run :

```
2016-08-22 11:21:02.465 Diamonds[16679:6710554]
<UITableView: 0x12e0a6200; frame = (0 55; 250 332); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x132106f50>; animations = { position=<CASpringAnimation: 0x1320e3b40>; bounds.origin=<CASpringAnimation: 0x132173610>; bounds.size=<CASpringAnimation: 0x132173700>; bounds.origin-2=<CASpringAnimation: 0x13215c1b0>; bounds.size-2=<CASpringAnimation: 0x13215c2a0>;
};
layer = <CALayer: 0x132105a20>; contentOffset: {0, 3609}; contentSize: {250, 3941.197265625}>
```

After coming from background :

```
2016-08-22 11:19:51.910 Diamonds[16676:6709818]
<UITableView: 0x1388e2e00; frame = (0 55; 250 0);clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x13ca33040>; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c9e2bf0>; contentOffset: {0, 3125}; contentSize: {250, 3855.68359375}>
```

**EDIT**

I ALSO found one bug that when i added object to arrayChat is added but when i reload data 2nd time than last object that added after app coming from background it lost.

Comment: Did you check that array has objects?

Comment: yes it add new object.. and its count also increase in numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: yes im sure... i scroll by my self also

Comment: Can you print the arrayChat?

Comment: I believe your `arrayChat` object loses reference.

Comment: i printed arrayChat and it show text added, and also called numberOfRowsInSection where i printed count and increase also,,, but not called cellForRowAtIndexPath..

Comment: When your app in background you should handle the received message... by push notification.

Comment: yea i handle it by push but when i coming from background it not reloading table...

Comment: try `[table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];` or  `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(){
  //Perform action on main thread
    tableView.reloadData();
  }`

Comment: Put `[arrayChat addObject:messageContent];` in the main queue block.

Comment: please check my updated question.

Comment: first of all you must put
    [self.tblChat scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath
                            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                    animated:YES];
in the main thread

Answer (score 0):

You want to complete the time consuming data loading stuff in a background thread, then update the UI/Cells when your data is ready on the main thread.

```
 dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Queue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
            [self loadData];
        });

-(void)loadData
{
    // Expensive operations  add/remove data to NSArray or NSDictionary
     .
     .     
    // Operation done - now let's update our table cells on the main thread  

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tblChat reloadData];
    });
}
```

Comment: not working,... i added this code ... but last object added to array and when i reload table again than it disappear from array.